# jQuery Accordion Wizard within Kendo Grid custom pop-up editor template

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble getting the jQuery code to run inside the Kendo Grid Editor popup.

I'm trying to use this: http://sathomas.me/acc-wizard/

I can get the accordion to display within the popup edit window no problems. The accordion functions but there is no link between the numbered steps in the left hand column as there should be (see example).

I'm using the edit event of the Kendo grid to run this code but it falls over at this point.

```
  $(window).load(function () {
        $(".acc-wizard").accwizard({ onNext: onNext });
           })
```

My guess is that the Kendo pop-up is masking the .acc-wizard element within.

Does anyone have any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you share all your code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no link between..."? Do you mean that clicking on the headlines on the left does nothing or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed

I had to add this code to the onEdit function of the Kendo Grid.

```
 function onNext(parent, panel) {      
    }

    element2 = e.container.find(".acc-wizard");
    element2.accwizard({ onNext: onNext });
```